# Rescue mode right after installation

Tags: grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I recently installed Ubuntu on my computer. I installed it on my 2nd hard drive with the mandatory partitions (Root, /home, etc.), and installed correctly. When it was finished, I restarted my computer, and instead of a "OS select" like screen (I had windows 8.1 on my 1st hard drive) I saw this:

```
Error: No such device: d2201c51-23a0-4c39-ba50-272d67f4779f
Entering rescue mode...
```

This made me extremely worried and confused, so I tried using commands like I would in MS-DOS and such (win, Help, etc.), including typing in "help me."

Help me...

Answer (score 0):

I am reproducing my answer to a similar question.

At the `grub prompt` try these commands:

```
set pager=1
ls
```

Now, suppose the output of ls is: `(hd0) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)`, in order to find the linux root filesystem run:

`ls (hd0,1)/` which should give you all the files/folders in `/` such as `bin/ boot/ cdrom/ dev/ etc/ home/  lib/` etc.

Once this is done continue with:

```
set root=(hd0,1)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generic root=/dev/sda1
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic
boot
```

Of course replace `vmlinuz-3.13.0-29-generi`c and `initrd.img-3.13.0-29-generic` with what you find in your `/boot`

`/dev/sda1` is the location of the root system. You may have to change it if `/dev/sda1` did not work. You may have to even change it to `sdb1` if the Ubuntu is in another hard disk (in which case even the first `ls` command will list `hd1` which means second hard disk). The best place to refer is the article from [linux.com](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/)

Once you are in Ubuntu , it is best to use the [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool from Ubuntu to fix common booting problems.

Comment: At ls (hd0,1)/ I got this: Error: unknown file system

Comment: may be your Ubuntu is in your second harddrive, so it will be hd1..? what does the first `ls` give you?

Comment: (Hd0), (hd0,msdos2), and (hd0,msdos1).